# Player prefs is not saving data with error Namespaces cannot be used as expressions.?

Tags: unity, unityscript

code:

```
var score:GameObject;
function OnCollisionEnter(){


PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Score",score.GetComponent(Events).i);


}
```

*Events* is the script I assigned to gameObject *score* which contain the float variable *i*.

I am trying to access this var from another function.

But it give an error as-

```
'Events' is a namespace. Namespaces cannot be used as expressions.
```

when I give quotation mark in *Events* it does not give any error initially But when *OnCollisionEnter* is called it gives an error as-

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here, the namespace Events is already defined in Unity, change your script's name from Events to something else.

https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html

The UnityEngine has a Events namespace.

Comment: No I have assigned the gameObject containing Events script to the score variable

Comment: edited my answer.